# How i can move the gridline behind the bar chart ( D3)

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

i want to move the gridline behind the bar chart ,actually i print the gridlines before the bars on the upgradeChart() function , any suggestions?
I need the gridlines :) i cant delete them.
Here my code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as _d3Tip from 'd3-tip';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-histogram',
  templateUrl: './histogram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./histogram.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HistogramComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
   @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
   @Input() public config;
    private chart;
    private margin;
    private width;
    private height;
    private xScale;
    private yScale;
    private xAxis;
    private yAxis;
    private element;
    private svg;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.config);
    this.createChart( );
    if (this.config.data) {
      this.updateChart();
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.updateChart();
    }
  }

  public createChart() {

// Traemos el elemento donde estará el gráfico en este caso #chart
this.element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

// Guardamos los datos en una constante
const data = this.config.data;

// Declaramos el margen, el ancho y la altura del gráfico según los estilos del div #chart (d3-chart)
this.margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
this.width = this.element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
this.height = this.element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

this.svg = d3.select(this.element).append('svg')
  .attr('width', this.element.offsetWidth)
  .attr('height', this.element.offsetHeight);

// chart plot area
this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'bars')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);

// Creamos las escalas
this.xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, this.width]).padding(0.3);
this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([this.height, 0]);

// Definimos la posicion del eje X en la parte de abajo
this.xAxis = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top + this.height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));

// Definimos la posicion del eje Y en la parte izquierda con su formato..
this.yAxis = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));


 }

  public updateChart() {

// Necesario al importar la libreria d3-tip para versiones superiores a 4 en d3.js
const d3Tip = _d3Tip.bind(d3);

// Creamos el tooltip
const tip = d3Tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
  return '<span class="highlight">' + d.valueY + '€' + '</span>';
});

this.svg.call(tip);

// Definimos los datos de las escalas
this.xScale.domain(this.config.data.map( d => d.valueX));
this.yScale.domain([0, d3.max(this.config.data, d => d.valueY)]);
this.xAxis.transition().call(d3.axisBottom(this.xScale));
this.yAxis.transition().call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale).tickSize(-this.width).ticks(4).tickFormat(d => d + '€'));

const update = this.chart.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(this.config.data);

  // remove exiting bars
  update.exit().remove();

  // update existing bars
  this.chart.selectAll('.bar').transition()
    .attr('x', d => this.xScale(d.valueX))
    .attr('y', d => this.yScale(d.valueY))
    .attr('width', d => this.xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', d => this.height - this.yScale(d.valueY));

    update
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('data-index', function(d, i) { return i; })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    .attr('x', d => this.xScale(d.valueX))
    .attr('y', d => this.yScale(d.valueY))
    .attr('width', this.xScale.bandwidth())
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(300)
    .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
    .attr('height', d => this.height - this.yScale(d.valueY));


 }

}
```

The problem is on this line:

```
this.yAxis.transition().call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale).tickSize(-this.width).ticks(4).tickFormat(d => d + '€'));
```

This line do the  gridline :

```
.tickSize(-this.width).ticks(4).tickFormat(d => d + '€')
```

I let one picture from my barChart
[Bar Chart d3.js v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RVRd.png)

**SOLUTION FOR GRIDLINES:**

the solution is putting this code :

```
    // chart plot area
this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
.attr('class', 'bars')
.attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`);
```

after this :

```
    // Definimos la posicion del eje Y en la parte izquierda con su formato..
this.yAxis = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${this.margin.left}, ${this.margin.top})`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(this.yScale));
```

**Edit: another questions:**

1. Someone knows how can be responsive my barchart?
2. I need to put a minimal bar when the value is 0 €, how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure without a fiddle but, svg initially did not have z-index. Elements were layered based on the DOM tree. So last drawn is shown on top. In your case I see:

```
this.xAxis = this.svg.append('g')...
```

and

```
this.yAxis = this.svg.append('g')..
```

Now instead of adding them as g elements directly on the svg, would you try creating an wrapper g for both axes:

```
this.wrapper = this.svg.append('g');
```

then instead of the above 2, do:

```
this.xAxis = this.wrapper.append('g')...
```

Make sure the wrapper g element is added before you add your elements.does that mitigate the issue?

For your other questions,

2 - there are multiple ways to make it responsive, one of the easiest is to use preserveAspectRatio="none" attribute on your svg and then control the div or whatever element that wraps your svg using css media queries. If you mean changing the way the axes etc is drawn, then you have to call an update function that will update these elements on window `"resize"` event.

3 - Use Math.max and Math.min when setting your x, y or width height or transform attributes on your chart like

```
.attr("height",function(d,i){return Math.min(someMin,someScale(d))})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I edited the solution for that :)

Comment: np, I added some suggestions for other questions as well

Comment: i call my bar chart on the html with:
<div class="d3-chart" #chart ></div>
How i can use preserveAspectRatio?

Comment: On your svg: `<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"...`But first define me what you mean by responsive, adjusting the size of the graph or adjusting the number of gridlines based on the size of the viewport?

Comment: just adjusting the size of the graph if the resolution change

Comment: yeah great than use the preserveAspectRatio="none" on your svg, let it expand to full size of your wrapper div and then control the div size with css media queries.

Comment: I call my graph with: <div class="d3-chart" #chart ></div> , If i put inside the div a <svg></svg> this happen
https://ibb.co/dWkGpH , it goes down .S

Comment: On your svg add this for short check: `<svg style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"` and make sure your wrapper div has a position of absolute or relative. If you can provide a fiddle I can help maybe.

Comment: cool that styles works thanks! but now with preserveAspectRatio='none' didnt work i change the resolution and doesnt adjust the size of the graph

Comment: Make sure your svg expands in your div by setting styles on it: width:80%;height:60%;margin:auto;display:block; Now you need to set some [css @media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) .

Comment: Thanks, d3.max worked :) , just let do responsive the barChart

Comment: something like \@media screen and (max-width:1000px){div.wrapper{width:90%;height:300px;}
} \@media screen and (min-width:1001px){div.wrapper{width:60%;height:600px}} etc??